# iPhone SDK - Changing Xib files (partial curl)

Tags: iphone

I am creating an iPhone app for iOS 4 using the newest SDK.

On one of my pages I would like the user to click a thumbnail of a photo and then a partial curl transition style take affect to show a full sized version of the image.

On the page with the full sized image I have a toolbar with a "Back" button and a "Select" button.

When I click the Back button the partial curls rolls back down to my first Xib.

BUT when I click the Select button, the app crashes.

Can anyone help me or explain why it is doing this? Thanks!

.m file:

```
-(IBAction)switchViews4 {

ImagePicker *image = [[ImagePicker alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
image.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:image animated:YES];
[image release];
```

}

Comment: Without any code we can't help you.

Comment: This code works like a charm, although I used the presentModalViewController with a view controller instead of an ImagePicker. thank you.!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any other code, it is difficult to know why. But one guess is that you have a reference counting problem. Try:

```
-(IBAction)switchViews4 {
   ImagePicker *image = [[[ImagePicker alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
   image.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
   [self presentModalViewController:image animated:YES];
}
```

and see if it helps.